# Error CS1061 'Expence' does not contain a definition for 'Expence_Name' and no extension method 'Expence_Name'

Tags: c#

I create one class `Expence`

```
public class Expence
{
    public int Expence_ID { get; set; }
    public String Expence_Name { get; set; }
    public String Expence_Type { get; set; }
    public double Paid_Cost { get; set; }
    public String Payment_Type { get; set; }
    public String CheckNo { get; set; }
    public String Bank_Name { get; set; }
    public String DD_No { get; set; }
    public String NEFT_No { get; set; }
    public String Payment_Paid_To { get; set; }
}
```

It use on different location like click event

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Expence exp = new Expence();
   exp.Expence_Name
}
```

> Error  CS1061  'Expence' does not contain a definition for 'Expence_Name' and 
>   no extension method 'Expence_Name' accepting a first argument of type 'Expence' could be found 
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `exp.Expence_Name` on its own will not compile, whats the *real* line that's failing?

Comment: @AlexK. is right, you aren't doing anything with that line `exp.Expence_Name` in your `btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. There isn't even `;` Your code is simply unfinished.

Comment: And just in case is the name space the same or used to reference it?

Comment: As others have said the code above isn't finished; if you replace exp.Expence_Name with something like exp.Expence_Name = "test"; then the code will compile, as it stands it won't so its not possible to know the issue as is.